# stacked BarChart shows no edges for big list of data

Tags: charts

For big numbers of columns, a stacked `BarChart` does not display edges anymore. For low numbers of columns they appear again. Is there a way to force Mathematica displaying the edges, even for big lists?

Here is an example:

no edges:

```
BarChart[Table[RandomReal[9], {i, 35}, {j, 11}], 
ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarSpacing -> None]
```

with edges:

```
BarChart[Table[RandomReal[9], {i, 5}, {j, 11}], 
ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarSpacing -> None]
```

Thank you very much for your help!!

All the best,
Kilian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bc = BarChart[Table[RandomReal[9], {i, 35}, {j, 11}], 
   ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarSpacing -> None]
```

[image]

Somehow, the rectangles are rendered with the directive

```
EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0.]]
```

when the input data is larger than some threshold.

You can post-process the output to change `Opacity[0.]` to `Opacity[1.]`:

```
bc /.  Opacity[0.] -> Opacity[1.]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much... You rescue my evening;) Good job!!

Comment: @Kilian, glad it was useful. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

I think @kglr has hit on the core issue of the problem by noting the addition of the `Opacity` directive once you cross a threshold.

If you want to include the solution in the code, you can specify it with `ChartStyle` and`EdgeForm` directly.

```
BarChart[Table[RandomReal[9], {i, 35}, {j, 11}], 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarSpacing -> None, 
 ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thin, Opacity[1]}]]
```